# Facebook with Membership Provider?

Tags: sql, facebook, asp.net-membership, schema, forms-authentication

I am using Facebook connect for my project with custom written code to deal with authentication, Do you suggest using Membership provider to deal with users or should i develop some custom Database in Backend.

Please give a hint on how to do in any of the above ways....

**Update**

with custom Database i mean Developing a Custom membership Provider

**Update**

Please suggest what should be the schema of the Custom Database for the custom Membership provider

Comment: What data are you trying to store?

Comment: User data ofcourse... but default membership database is dosent seem to have tables for holding data for Cookie infos, session token, etc.

Comment: It is illegal to store anything related to user other than user id.

Comment: @zerkms Oh common obviously i won't be storing user passwords (but hash), only is prefrences, and for user profile info, it not on my server at all, insted i am getting it from Facebook graph API.

Answer (score 0):

The membership database is primarily for storing usernames and passwords, definitely not for storing cookies or session. I'm not familiar with how facebook connect works, but I'm guessing you can't even store the password.  If you can't manage passwords there's no reason use to asp.net membership.

My suggestion is to compare the membership database against your own concept for the database and see if there's any real overlap....I'm guessing there isn't.

http://superpatrick.wordpress.com/2007/11/21/aspnet-membership-schema/